# Regex to split up string of CPU usage percentages?

Tags: regex, prtg

We have an HP 1920S switch and the only way to get the CPU usage via SNMP is an OID I found here: https://community.hpe.com/t5/Web-and-Unmanaged/HP-1920s-OID-CPU-Utilization-and-memory/td-p/7001413

OID: `.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.5.7.5.7.1.1.1.1.4.9.0`

When queried via SNMP that OID returns values like this:

```
 5 Secs ( 22.3463%) 60 Secs ( 25.677%) 300 Secs ( 21.3522%)
 5 Secs ( 13.6713%) 60 Secs ( 15.3520%) 300 Secs ( 15.9640%)
```

So the 5 second CPU utilization average is 22%, 60 second was 25%, and 5 minute was 21%. Then the next time I queried it was 13, 15, and 15 percent.

Is there a way via regex to discretely match the 5 second percentage or discretely match the 60 second percentage or the 5 minute percentage? The goal is to wire this up to a few SNMP Custom String sensors in PRTG, so then it can alert if the 5 minute average is above 80%, for example.
I did fine this regex here: `\d+(\%|\s\bpercent\b)` via https://www.regextester.com/95112 but I also can't figure out how to modify it for my needs and can't get it to work on regex101.com

Thank you!

Comment: You might create a full pattern and use 3 capturing groups for all the percentages. For example: `^\s*\d+\s+Secs\s*\(\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)$` https://regex101.com/r/8PqwXK/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\d+(\%|\s\bpercent\b)` will not match the decimal part in the example string.

You could add matching an optional decimal part `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\%|\s\bpercent\b)` , but you will get 3 matches and the pattern does not match `Secs`

Your query returned 2 times the same structure for the data. One way could be using a pattern that matches the full line and use 3 capturing groups so you know which group has which value.

There is not word `percentage` in the example data, so you could just use `%` instead.

```
^\s*\d+\s+Secs\s*\(\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8PqwXK/1)

Comment: Thank you; how do you split that up to create a regex for the 5 secs value, one for the 60 secs value, and one for the 300 secs value?

Comment: @cvocvo You could do that using a quantifier `{n}` for example `^(?:\s*\d+\s+Secs\s*\(\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\))` to get the first or  `^(?:\s*\d+\s+Secs\s*\(\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)){2}` to get the second etc https://regex101.com/r/6hszTy/1 or `^(?:\s*\d+\s+Secs\s*\(\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)){3}`  to get the third https://regex101.com/r/52gN8w/1 and in all 3 cases, the value is in capture group 1.